# Davicom DM9601 USB LAN NIC Ubuntu 11.10 issue

Tags: drivers, usb, network-manager, ethernet

I have a davicom dm9601 USB ethernet card.

When I plug in the device, it is detected and drivers are
loaded, but I can't connect to internet using it.

It works perfectly on XP, other laptop but not working on Ubuntu 11.10

How can I install the driver for this? I have tried many things But nothing is working.

If I go to this link [driver but not compiling](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=869618) or may I be doing something wrong.

[I found this one](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man4/udav.4freebsd.html) but don't know how to follow these steps .

This is my `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 002
Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 003 Device
001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 004 Device 001: ID
1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 005 Device 001: ID
1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 006 Device 001: ID
1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 007 Device 001: ID
1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 008 Device 001: ID
1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 002 Device 004: ID
064e:a103 Suyin Corp. Acer/HP Integrated Webcam [CN0314] Bus 003
Device 002: ID 08ff:1600 AuthenTec, Inc. AES1600 Bus 005 Device 002:
ID 0a46:9601 Davicom Semiconductor, Inc. DM9601 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c045 Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse Bus 003
Device 003: ID 0a5c:2101 Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth Controller Bus 004
Device 002: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
```

But when I connected my Internet from different system its start working.

Comment: maybe use that other driver on ubuntu forums

Comment: can u specify which driver

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=79157&d=1217190597

Comment: tried it also contain error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pre-Requirements**

You will need the `build-essential` and `linux-headers-generic` packages to install. If you do not have these packages, you can find them on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), download the `*.deb` files and manually install them.

`linux-headers-generic` is a virtual packages that installs the correct headers for the current kernel you're running. You can find that out by typing `uname -r` in the terminal. Mine is `3.0.0-17-generic`. That means what I should really download is the `linux-headers-3.0.0-17-generic` package. Once you have your ethernet work, `apt-get install linux-kernel-headers` so you always have the correct headers.

The `build-essential` package has a lot of dependancies, and when you attempt to install the `.deb` file it will tell you what is missing. Go back to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) and download all of the `*.debs` for the packages it complains about.

If you're running Ubuntu, `*.deb` files can be installed by double clicking on them. On Kubuntu, you need to right click and choose the install option.

Build the module
Goto [Davicom's website](http://www.meworks.net/userfile/24247/dm9601-Linux2.6_1_1.tar) and download the `LINUX Driver` to your home folder.
Open up the Terminal and type `tar -xzvf dm9601-Linux2.6_1_1` to extract it.
Type `cd dm9601` to enter the newly created folder.
Type `gedit dm9601.c` to edit the broken source file.
Change `#include <linux/config.h>` to `#include <linux/configfs.h>`
Save the file and close gedit.
Type `make` to build the module.

Ok, now you've built the module. At this point we can test it. With your Davicom USB adapter plugged in, type `sudo insmod dm9601.ko` to temporarily insert the module. If everything works, we need to make this module insert automatically on bootup.

Insert the module on bootup
Type `sudo cp dm9601.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/ubuntu/net/`
type `sudo gedit /etc/modules`
Add `dm9601` on it's own line at the end of the file
Save and exit gedit.

Your module should now work on reboot. Congratulations! You will need to repeat steps 2,3 & 7 from the Build stage and step 1 from the Insert stage whenever you install a kernel update.

Troubleshooting
If insmod failed to work, you probably need to add your USB device ID to the header file.

Type 'lsmod' and look for a line that belongs to your Davicom USB adapter. It should look similar to "Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0a46:9555 Davicom Semiconductor, Inc." If you have doubt, unplug all other USB devices and find the only line that doesn't have "0000:0000".

For the example above, type `gedit dm9601.h` and insert 2 lines that look like:

```
DM9601_DEV( "Davicom Semiconductor, Inc", VENDOR_ACCTON, 0x0a46, 0x9555,
                DEFAULT_GPIO_RESET )
```

Your module source code is now configured to recognize your module. Continue from Step 6 in the Build stage of the instructions.

Comment: But Compilation [error](http://paste.ubuntu.com/904718/) is come in this way also .

Comment: If all else fails use Ndiswrapper and Windows Drivers

Comment: but its works for wireless card i hope

Answer (score 0):

This is the file you need to use : [Linux Driver DM9601](http://www.meworks.net/userfile/24247/dm9601-Linux2.6_1_1.tar)

This is the manufacture [source](http://www.davicom.com.tw/page1.aspx?no=209814)

This is how you install it : [Compile and install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo)

If all else fails use [Ndiswrapper](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper) and Windows Drivers

Comment: i have Compilation problem when i tried to compile that Linux Driver its shows me error i am posting [error](http://paste.ubuntu.com/904718/). u may edit ur answer